# Teamfoundation library 12.0 fakes not getting added as a reference in VS 2013

Tags: c#, unit-testing, visual-studio-2013, tfs-workitem, microsoft-fakes

When i try to add the fake assembly for Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client then it created the

Microsoft.QualityTools.Testing.Fakes.dll - Added to the reference

Fakes folder was created and the file in it consisted of the below lines

```
<Fakes xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/fakes/2011/">
  <Assembly Name="Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client" Version="12.0.0.0"/>
</Fakes>
```

I saw a video on a training website and in that the fakes file also gets added as part of the reference and which we can use object explorer to see the available fake definitions

Is there anything that i am doing wrong? Is there other ways people have tested the calls made to Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client ?

Or do i have to create my own stub class to fake?

Answer (score 0):

Fakes assemblies are generated when you ask IDE to generate the fake assembly by right clicking on assembly name, then 'Add Fakes assembly'

IDE starts a build process automatically (in the background) to generate the *.fake.dll file and the reference should be added to your project as well.

If you look at your project directory you will see there is a new folder 'FakeAssemblies' that contains the automatically generated dlls, you can always look there to confirm the assembly has been generated and add the reference to your project if its missing.

(There is no other way to generate the fakes assemblies)

Comment: Yep true. My issue is that Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.Fakes.dll wasn't generated by the process u mentioned above. Microsoft.QualityTools.Testing.Fakes was generated and added to the references automatically

Comment: Try a rebuild all command, this should get rid of this issue, double check output folder...